# Decomposition of the symmetric square of the standard representation of the symetric group

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory

As C Monsour already ansered part of my question, I edit it.

The only remaining question is how to decompose into irreducible representations the symmetric square $V$ of the standard representation $\phi$ of the symmetric group? Everything is defined in the following, which I kept inchanged:

I'd like to decompose and find an adapted basis for the decomposition into irreducible of the following representation:

Consider the symetric groupe $S_n$, acting over $\{e_i\}$, the canonical basis of $\Bbb{C}^n$ by permutation of indices.
Then the standard representation $\phi$ of $S_n$ is generated by the $\delta^-_{ij}=e_i-e_j$.

I would like to decompose into irreducible the representation $\phi\otimes\phi$. I found a first stable subspace which is I guess irreducible:

- $V$ generated by the $\delta^-_{ij}\otimes\delta^-_{ij}$ is stable, of dimension $n(n-1)/2$.
- Then its orthogonal representation $W$, of dimension $(n-1)(n-2)/2$, is also stable.

I have the following questions:

1. is $V$ irreducible in general?
2. is $W$ irreducible in general?
3. is it possible to easely exibit a basis of $W$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify, you are asking specifically about representations over $\Bbb{R}$ not $\Bbb{C}$, yes?

Comment: No sorry, C is good!

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the revised question, the symmetric square of $\phi$ decomposes as a sum of three irreducible representations: The principal character, the standard representation, and an irreducible representation of dimension $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$.  See the formula near the top of page four in Bowman et al (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5579.pdf), where the other representation in the sum is the alternating square.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for!
Then I still have a question (sorry ;) ):
I'd like to have basis element for each of those subspaces. Either in terms of the $\delta^-_{ij}\otimes\delta^-_{ij}$ or in terms of the $\zeta_i\otimes\zeta_j+\zeta_j\otimes\zeta_i$.

Comment: Ok so I guess it should not be that hard. The trivial rep is given by the sum of all elements. And I guess the rest should be understandable from low n exemples.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your notation is confusing.  Let $\zeta_i=e_{1+1}-e_i$ for $1\le i \le n-1$.  Then the $\zeta_i$ are a linear basis for $\phi$, the $\zeta_i \otimes \zeta_j +  \zeta_j \otimes \zeta_i$ for $1\le i\le j\le n-1$ are a basis for $V$ and the $\zeta_i \otimes \zeta_j -  \zeta_j \otimes \zeta_i$, for $1\le i<j\le n-1$ are a basis of W.  If that is what you intended, that also answers (c).

In his book *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, Serre calls $V$ and $W$ the symmetric and alternating squares of $\phi$.

$\phi$ is codimension 1 in the natural permutation representation of $S_n$.  It is irreducible based on standard results about multiply transitive permutation groups.  (See, e.g., [Representation of multiply transitive group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60468/representation-of-multiply-transitive-group) .)

(a): In general $V$ cannot be irreducible.  For example, for $S_5$, $\dim V=10$ but no irreducible representation has dimension larger than $6$, as you can tell by looking up or constructing the character table.

(b): While alternating squares of irreducibles are not in general irreducible  (if the highest dimension irreducible has dimension at least $5$ then its alternating square is never irreducible, for example), I'm fairly certain the alternating square of $\phi$ is irreducible.  I don't recall the proof, however.  There is a lot of literature on the representation theory of the symmetric group, on which I am not an expert.  I am sure you can find a detailed answer there.  But I suspect you can find a proof that just relies on the multiple transitivity of $S_n$.

(c) See above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then I need to understand in general how to decompose $V$, the symmetric square of $\phi$.

For (b), I found this reference [link](https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/14380/1/TheorieRepresentationsGroupeSymetriqueVersOrbi.pdf) which gives a proof (theorem 3.1). It is in French, sorry.

Comment: I edited my question then. Do you know a reference where I could find an answer for this question? I looked a bit on the internet but didn't find the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: The answer (without a full proof) about the decomposition of the symmetric square is contained in bottom of slide 8 of http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/wpe006/skye2009/presentations/orlob-presentation.pdf, but you'll need to learn the language of Specht modules and the Robinson-Schensted correspondence to follow it.

Comment: Are you sure? I have the impression that this concerne representation of finite fields of p>2 characteristic?
I found this reference from the same author: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Juergen.Mueller/preprints/jm31.pdf.
But again, it concerns finite fields.

Comment: Not finite fields necessarily, just odd characteristic, which always include characteristic larger than n, where the theory is basically the same as characteristic 0.  So even though he isn't talking about characteristic zero, that ought to work...(Actually, in the char 0 case you know the summands on the right are irreducible, which isn't always true in the modular case.)

Comment: But here's a reference that covers the char 0 case (at the top of p 4).  (Remember the of the four terms, one is the alternating square  The other 3 add to the symmetric square.) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5579.pdf.  Also, there are decent introductions to Specht modules at http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/McNamara.pdf and http://math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/young_promys.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to C Monsour I found the answer.

First look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5579.pdf page 4.
The correspondance in notations are $\phi:=S(n-1,1), T:=S(n), \psi=S(n-2,1^2), W=S(n-2,1^2)$.

It is said that $\phi\otimes\phi=T\oplus\phi\oplus\psi\oplus W$.
We already have a basis for $W$ and for $V:=T\oplus\phi\oplus\psi$.

In the following I give explicit correspondence with the usual way of presenting $T$ and $\phi$. As $\psi$ is the orthogonal space of $T\oplus\phi$, it is sufficient.

A basis of $V$ is given by the $\{\alpha_{ij}\}_{i<j}$ where $\alpha_{ij}:=\delta_{ij}^-\otimes \delta_{ij}^-$ (remark that $\alpha_{ij}=\alpha_{ji}$).
Let 
$$t=\sum_{i<j}\alpha_{ij}$$ and
$$e_k=\sum_{i\neq k} \alpha_{ik}-\sum_{i,j\neq k;i\neq j} \alpha_{ij}+\lambda t,$$ where $\lambda$ is chosen such that $t$ and $e_k$ are orthogonals.

Then, $t$ clearly generates the trivial irrep $T$.
Moreover, the e_k generates a space of dimension $n-1$ and a permutation $\sigma$ applied to $e_k$ gives $\sigma(e_k)=e_{\sigma(k)}$. This space is $\phi$ and the $e_k$ are the vertex of a regular polytope in dimension $n$.